# What should I call a person from New Zealand?

Tags: nouns, demonyms, ethnonyms

The question [“They are Australian” vs “They are Australians”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304897/they-are-australian-vs-they-are-australians) on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) made me think of what people from New Zealand should be called. With Australian people it's quite clear, you can say:

> one Australian, two Australians, three Australians...

How would this be done with people from New Zealand? Is there a general rule to apply to all people coming from countries ending with -*land*?

In case of New Zealand, an alternative would be:

> one Kiwi, two Kiwis, three Kiwis...

but this isn't really what I'm looking for.

Comment: As a New Zealander... I can confirm, it's **New Zealander**. _Kiwi_ doesn't really work as a plural for a group of New Zealanders.

Comment: @MathiasFoster You need to have some more experience when editing any post. Your edit is an **attempt to reply**. The tag **grammatical-number** is not better than the tags Mari-Lou A used.

Comment: @Rathony the g-number tag was originally placed by the OP, as was the "edit". But I agree the grammatical number tag is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The thing is your tag edit was reversed, which was not necessary.

Comment: I preferred the OP's simple  "a Kiwi" than "one Kiwi, two Kiwis, three Kiwis..." suggested by Mathias, it sounds like the nursery rhyme: "one potato, two potato, three potato, four..." :)

Comment: @Rathony I think I submitted an edit just after Mari-Lou. I just left the tags as they were, and this must have appeared like I reversed Mari-Lou's edit when my edit was accepted. Thank you for fixing this, I agree that grammatical-number makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use one New Zealander, two New Zealanders... The name is unique in that it is composed of two words. Other countries whose names finish with "-land" don't have two words, e.g.:

> Finland, Ireland, Iceland, The Netherlands (*The* is a definite article), Poland, Swaziland,
>   Switzerland and Thailand, etc.

Among them, only Iceland has its adjective (language) and people with suffix "ic" and "er" as in Icelandic and Icelander. Other countries have Finnish, Irish, Dutch, Polish, Swazi, Swiss and Thai for their people respectively.

The adjective *New Zealandic* is sometimes used, but not very broadly.

[image]

There is no hard-and-fast rule to apply to all people coming from countries ending with -land.

Comment: I'm from New Zealand and I've never heard of _New Zealandic_. It seems far too contrived to be a word that actually gets used.

Comment: @MathiasFoster NZTE is the New Zealand government agency and that's why I used it as an example. It doesn't seem to be a typo.

Comment: I can't view that photo due to a firewall that blocks imgur, can you please transcribe it? I find it hard to believe that a New Zealand government agency would use that word at all.

Comment: @MathiasFoster You can find it on the 99th page of [this link](https://books.google.com/books?id=ndA3Pe6JCJIC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq="Commenting+on+the+New+Zealandic+government%27s+design"&source=bl&ots=AnfOCDaBZ2&sig=YYCjX82iNyNmCNi3_QI7lYFfm_M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0k9j1murKAhWBIKYKHdmNCt8Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Commenting%20on%20the%20New%20Zealandic%20government's%20design%22&f=false).

Comment: Unfortunately, one small problem... **extremely** zealous firewall. Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35484/discussion-between-mathias-foster-and-rathony).

Answer (score 4):

"New Zealander" is often used as a noun, and "New Zealand" attached to nouns where an adjective is needed (e.g. "New Zealand native".

There are too many counter-examples to come up with a general rule. "Englander" is only used in phrases such as: "little Englander" which has a rather specific meaning (an ignorant English nationalist); "New Englander" - a person from New England. In fact "New Zealander" is rather rare in how it forms, probably because there's no nice adjective unlike "English", "Scottish" etc. ("Kiwi" being informal akin to "Aussie" in your original example)

Comment: even though "Kiwi" is rather informal, it is interesting to know that it's broadly used in tv and radio...

Comment: @WayneEra I think that's common to many nicknames for people from a particular country when there's no engative connotation.

Comment: New Englander is common.

Comment: @ab2 of course it is. Edit on its way.

Answer (score 0):

New Zealand is the anglicised version of *Nieuw Zeeland* (Dutch), denoting *"new"* plus the province where the fleets before the Victorians provenated, *Zeeland*/Zealand, one of the Netherlands' largest provinces. Remember, at this time, Australia was *Nieuw Holland*, New Zealand...*Nieuw Zeeland*, and New York was *Nieuw Amsterdam*. 


Anyway, the denonym of someone from Zealand is a Zealander, but their accent of Dutch is Zealandic. *-Er* denotes a person, and *-ic* denotes a person (from French *-ic/-ique*). Eg. Netherlands: someone is a called a Netherlander and they speak Netherlandic. We started calling it Dutch because English speakers have ALWAYS had the worst language skills and confused it for the word *'Deutsch'* which means *'German'* in German, let alone the fact we call the country Holland, even though that's only a province. Which is why Pensylvania Dutch people, in the U.S.A., speak German and not Dutch. English, only about 60 years ago, became an important language, which is why now it's such an inconsistent language. (For all Aussies and Brits, it was U.S.A. that helped it beat French to number 1, not you guys, so get of ya high horse). 


When *'New'* is prepended, it becomes *'neo'* in its adjectival form and also prepends without space. 
      Eg., 
    New nazione = Neonazi
    New class = Neoclassical
    New York = Neoyorker

**SUMMMARY**

Someone from New Zealand should, technically be called a Neozealander, and the English spoken in New Zealand should be called Neozealandic English, or wow, step back, Neozealandico-english. New Zealand's prefix is *Neozealandico-*. 

  For example, consider:
    Franco-german war = French German war
    Afro-american person = African American person
    Italo-australian food = Italian Australian food
    Ferro-sulphate = Iron sulphate
    Franco-provencal speakers = French Provincial speakers
    Neozealandico-australian alliance = New Zelalander Australian alliance
    


Before someone replies with how offended they are, I have a degree in English, French and linguistics from Monash Uni (a university in Melbourne, Australia).

Comment: I have it on good authority that it is "[New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/)", not "Neoyorker". Also, do you have sources of "Neozealander" being used by someone else?

Comment: As a point of interest, do you have a source that anyone uses "Ferro-sulphate" other than yourself. Not important as it's beside the point of the question, but it does seem to me that you might be being somewhat inventive here; that's not realy the purpose of the site.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you might be interested in our [conlang.se] stack. It's a technical playground for linguists.

Comment: What exactly is the role of the word *technically* in the sentence 'Someone from New Zealand should, technically be called a Neozealander . . .'?

Comment: This seems more like a theory than what is in practical use today. It is interesting, but I'm not sure it actually answers the question.